# Delphi: Como obter informações e manipular Html em uma TStringList?

Tags: html, delphi, string, delphi-xe3, delphi-7

Trabalhando com o `TWebBrowser` é possível interagir com os elementos com facilidade, obter campos, setar valores.

Exemplo:

```delphi
webBrowser.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('name').setAttribute('attribute', 'value');
```

Minha pergunta pode estar ser bem irreal, mas alguém conhece uma forma de ser obter as tags, talvez até trabalhar algumas informações, de um código Html contido em uma `TStrings`, por exemplo, de forma mais flúida?

Dando um exemplo para ficar mais claro o que desejo:
Digamos que eu tenha recebido o html de uma página e quero obter o código html de algumas tags, obter alguns valores, talvez setar alguns para depois devolver, etc.

Comment: O HTML é um tipo de documento de marcação, como o XML. Como tal, você pode navegar em seus Nodos como um documento XML.

É possível criar/editar documentos html utilizando IXMLDocument, com um pouco de esforço

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma fácil que encontrei de fazer isso foi assim:

```delphi
var
  doc: variant;
  element: variant;
begin
  doc := coHTMLDocument.Create as IHTMLDocument2;
  doc.write(html);   
  doc.Close;
  ...
  element := doc.getElementById('elementId');
  ...
  element.getAttribute('value', 0);
end;
```

Baseado então em componentes COM do Windows.